# Change bin-address on mysql ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, localhost

I'm trying to change the bin-address of my localhost database instance on a ubuntu 18.04 computer

i went to `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` and then modified the file `mysqld.cnf` to assign the ip address i want `192.168.0.100.`

From bind-address = 127.0.0.1 to `bind-address = 192.168.0.100`

When i try `telnet 192.168.1.100 3306` after a while is see this message

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused;
```

Is this the best approach to change the ip address of my localhost instance?

Comment: From bind-address = 127.0.0.1 to `bind-address = 192.168.0.100`

Comment: Seems reasonable. What is in MySQL's log?

Comment: What does Log show, and does `netstat -anp | grep 3306` show you it is in `LISTEN` state?